# Difficulty parsing PDF files, using pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdf, text, extract

I am trying to parse quarterly investment statements to import transactions into Quicken as my provider (TSP for federal government) does not support online download. I think I have figured out how to create a "qif" file that can be used Quicken import.

I am using Python 3.8 and pdfplumber. Here is a snapshot from one of the pages in the pdf.

[image]
I need to parse transactions with a posting date from "Transaction Detail By Source". I need the name of the fund as well as the transaction with posting date for others. Here is my simple Python code -

```
import pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open(r'C:\Users\ra_d\\statements\Investments\TSP\1Q 2011.pdf') as pdf:
for x in pdf.pages :
    print (x.extract_text())
    #print (x.extract_words())
    #print (x.extract_tables())
```

Well, the good news is that I can parse the pdf and this output is generated for the portion in the image -

```
TRANSACTION DETAIL BY SOURCE
Agency
Payroll Posting Automatic Agency
Office Date Transaction Type Employee (1%) Matching Total
Beginning Balance $0.00 $0.00 $0.00 $0.00
12400001 03/22/11 Auto Enrollment Contribution             69.00 23.00 69.00 161.00
Increase/Decrease in Value 0.05 0.02 0.05 0.12
Ending Balance $69.05 $23.02 $69.05 $161.12
TRANSACTION DETAIL BY FUND
Government Securities Investment (G) Fund                   
Number       
Posting Transaction Share     of          Dollar      
Date Transaction Type Amount Price Shares Balance

Beginning Balance $13.4882 0.0000 $0.00
03/22/11 Auto Enrollment Contribution             $161.00 13.5752 11.8599
Ending Balance $13.5854 11.8599 $161.12
```

When I use the extract_tables() function, I get blanks.

So, I am looking for suggestions on how to improve this parsing. I need to get the headers and their values distinctly in order to process them accurately.

Thanks much.
RD

Answer (score 0):

```
def parser(filepath):
    L = []
    pdf = pdfplumber.open(filepath)
    for i in range(15):
        page = pdf.pages[i]
        try:
            table = page.extract_table()
            df = pd.DataFrame(table)
            if df.shape[0] > 1:
                df = df.drop([0,2,5,6,8], axis=1)
                for i in range(len(df)):
                    if df.iloc[i][4] != None:
                        df.iloc[i][3] = df.iloc[i][4]
                df = df.drop([4], axis=1)
                L.append(df)
            if "Всего" in table[-1]:
                break
        except Exception:
            continue
    df = pd.concat(L)
df.columns = ["Раздел", "Слова", "Важность"]
df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop([0,1])
return df
```

Comment: tar = ""


    MO = cvDF[cvDF["target"] == tar].drop("target",axis=1)

    for i in range(MO.shape[0]):
        for j in cvDF.drop("target",axis=1):
            if MO.iloc[i][j]>2:
                print(j,MO.iloc[i][j])